# Play Framework 2 - Scala template: How to call a specific method on a generic object?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, playframework-2.0, generic-programming, scala-template

I am using Play Framework 2.1.5 in a Java application.

I've got a view component that takes a list of generic objects as a parameter. In this component, I want to iterate on the list and get some properties of each element.

This would look like something like this:

```
@(elements: List[_])

@for((element, i) <- elements.view.zipWithIndex) {
    @i
    @element.id
    @element.name
}
```

(I need those 3 values)

But, of course, `element.id` and `element.name` would not compile even if the type of objects I put in the list contained these methods. So I did this:

```
@for((element, i) <- elements.view.zipWithIndex) {
    @defining(
        ViewsUtils.getGenericElementId(element),
        ViewsUtils.getGenericElementName(element)) {
            case (id, name, something) =>
                @i
                @id
                @name
        }
}
```

And in a Java utility class:

```
public final class ViewsUtils {

    public static String getGenericElementId(Object object) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        return object.getClass().getMethod("getId").invoke(object).toString();
    }

    public static String getGenericElementName(Object object) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        return object.getClass().getMethod("getName").invoke(object).toString();
    }
}
```

This works but I know it's not right because it could throw a RuntimeException in case one of these methods didn't exist for the type of object I put in the list.

Here are my suppositons:

1. Casting the elements
2. Using inheritance
3. As I just need 2 properties of each object (id and name), I could use a map, but I need the index of the loop (is it possible to get it from a map?) and it wouldn't work if I needed more than 2 properties.
4. Maybe Scala provides the syntax for this kind of stuff.

Or maybe I'm just looking in the wrong direction.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not pass a `@(elements: List[GenericObject])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that is a bit too much for a comment, so I'll risk to post it as an answer.

Assuming you wish to never get a `RuntimeException` you mentioned it makes sense that your object implement some interface (or mix in a trait, as it is said in Scala), so you won't risk getting an exception and no more need reflection to get values.

Suppose, you declare such a trait:

```
trait GenericObject {
  val id: Long
  val name: String
}
```

Then you declare some case classes:

```
case class A(id: Long, name: String, someOtherField: SomeType) extends GenericObject {
  //your implementation
}

case class B(id: Long, name: String) extends GenericObject

case class C(id: Long, name: String) extends B(id, name)
```

Now you can change your template like this:

```
@(elements: List[GenericObject])

@for((element, i) <- elements.view.zipWithIndex) {
  @i
  @element.id
  @element.name
}
```

And you should pass the list of `GenericObject`s to your template:

```
val myObjects: List[GenericObject] = List(A(1, "A name"), B(2, "B name"), C(3, "C name"))
Ok(your_template.scala.html(myObjects))
```

Comment: Yes, that would be a nice solution. I will let this unanswered for a few days to see if there is any other suggestion, but this is what I am looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a small problem: I am using Java. If I understand correctly, a trait in Scala is similar to - but less powerfull than - an interface in Java. I can only declare methods that have to be implemented, not properties. So I have to declare new methods where I used to access my properties directly as public. Perhaps I am being too needy.

Comment: @Thomas You can stick to Java if that's what you're using. I think what you want is to make `GenericObject` an abstract class. Same idea as serejja's answer, but GenericObject is an abstract class with your `id` and `name` fields.

Comment: I thought of that, but the objects I am working with are entity beans. I would try inheritance but it's becoming too complex for something I think is quite simple. Don't you think?